# Retorno dados do SQL mysqli_fetch_assoc organizados em uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte SQL

```
<?php

   require_once("php/conexao.php");

   $strSQL = "SELECT id, titulo FROM questoes ORDER by id DESC";

   if($result = mysqli_query($conexao, $strSQL)) {

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $ID = $row['id'];
         $titulo = $row['titulo'];
      }
   }
?>
```

E a seguinte tabela:

```
<div class="row tabela">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Lista de Questões</h3>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <span class="clickable filter" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Toggle table filter" data-container="body">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dev-table-filter" data-action="filter" data-filters="#dev-table" placeholder="Filter Developers" />
                    </div>
                    <table class="table table-hover" id="dev-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Título da Questão</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>Exemplo</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>Exemplo</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>Exemplo</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Estou tentando organizar os dados "ID" e "titulo" que retiro do SQL de forma correta na tabela, mas estou batendo bastante a cabeça. É uma duvida bem principiante, mas realmente estou sem um caminho, rs. Sou iniciante no PHP e SQL e é meu primeiro sisteminha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que *printar* os dados no meio do seu html:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="dev-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Título da Questão</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $ID = $row['id'];
            $titulo = $row['titulo'];
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $ID; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $titulo; ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php 
        } // fecha while
        ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Claro que estou considerando que essa query esteja sendo feita no mesmo arquivo - e antes - tabela.

Comment: Amigo, perfeito! Estava na cara o resultado, mas clareou minha mente você colocando dessa forma. Ajeitei do jeito do meu código aqui e ficou perfeito, claro, só tive que trocar a consulta do SQL para ASC que deu tudo OK. Mais uma vez obrigado pela ajuda, novamente!

Comment: @RodrigoBRF tranquilo amigo, precisando estamos aí!!